# Custom .Net MVC action parameter names inside a type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a web application which will receive form data from another service. This other service posts its data using a data model with snake case which I can parse using the default model binder by defining the data model below:

```
public class OtherServiceModel 
{
    public string property { get; set; }
    public DateTime another_property { get; set; }
    public CustomType one_more_property { get; set; }
}
```

and using the following action:

```
public ActionResult PostFromOtherService(OtherServiceModel model)
```

Now, for many reasons, I would really want to use this model instead:

```
public class OtherServiceModel 
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public DateTime AnotherProperty { get; set; }
    public CustomType OneMoreProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible without having to create my own model binder? Or is there an easy solution using a custom model binder?

I'm aware of the [Bind] attribute but, for many reasons, I can't define all of my action parameters directly in the action method signature (I need a type defining the model).

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` works by match the form data names to property names. Its not case sensitive but `another_property` will not match `AnotherProperty` because of the underscore character. You will need a custom model binder

Comment: Alternatively just create a separate model for binding and then map its properties to your `OtherServiceModel`